# Discord.py v1.7.3: Retrieving every embed from a channel and 'randomly' picking one to send as a message

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, discord.py

**What I'm trying to do:** I am attempting to create a command that searches the history of a specific discord channel, creates an index of every embed in it, and then 'randomly' selects one. Once it had done so, I intended it to forward the description of the embed so that the content of the embed was available in the channel the command was called in.

**Problem:**  It somewhat 'works' in that it retrieves embeds within the channel specified and forwards it to the channel called in, but I specifically wanted to get the embed descriptions instead of this:`<Message id=id channel=<TextChannel id=id name='general' position=0 nsfw=False news=False category_id=id> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=id name='name' discriminator='id' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>`

Originally, I had intended to actually include any attachments within the embed as well, but I couldn't even get the description alone so I quickly gave up on that until I could at least figure *this* out with my meager knowledge. Unfortunately I'm at a complete loss at what to do at this point.

```
@commands.command(name="emb", brief="Rolls for HoF entries.", case_insensitive=True)
async def get_embeds(self, ctx):
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(int(503998241193328672))
    all_messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=500).flatten()
    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        async for message in channel.history(limit=500):
            all_messages.append(message.embeds)
    message_to_send = random.choice(all_messages)
    await ctx.send(message_to_send)
    await ctx.send('Here you go {}'.format(ctx.author.mention))
```

Answer (score -1):

You have just got the Message object. Ironically what you don’t want is what you need to get the embed description.
Access the description like so:
`message_to_send.embeds[0].description`

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, or if I just come off as plain dumb: I receive `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'embeds'` due to `await ctx.send(message_to_send.embeds[0].description)` after attempting to access the description as you described. Have I misunderstood something, here?

Comment: You're appending a list of `Embed` instead of `Message` in your loop:
`all_messages.append(message.embeds)` -> simply remove the `.embeds` part

Comment: it’s misleading because the variable name is message_to_send while it’s holding information of an embed